# accessing to dataframe rows in pandas takes much time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on some data in a csv file that has 5872 rows. I want to change the time format and store it in that rows again.
I have this code for it:

```
for row in df.index:
    s = str(df['TimeTag'][row])
    df['TimeTag'][row] = jdt.datetime(int(s[0:4]), int(s[4:6]), 
                                      int(s[6:8]), int(s[8:10]),
                                      int(s[10:12]), 
                                      int(s[12:14])).togregorian()
```

but it takes too much time! about 10 minutes.
I think the problem is for storing that takes too much time. I've checked the function and that didn't have a time problem.

Comment: Can you add data sample of `TimeTag` to question?

Comment: im not sure about optimizations, but you might want to try a column operation using [map](http://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-examples-column-operations#apply-function-to-column) instead of going row by row. i found [this](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) article talking about efficiently doing this sort of thing

Comment: Instead of itterating over each row, have a look at the *append* function. And can you add an example dataframe and desired output?